# ASP.NET MVC - Submit Form DropDownListFor Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and trying to learn how to submit form with validation. My Create view is working fine, it lists the fields with dropdownlists, but when I Submit, I received this error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`.  I've been reading for hours and couldn't get it working.  Need help...!

Here is my class for Company:

```
[Table("tblCompany")]
public class Company
{

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Profile")]
    public string Type2 { get; set; }
    public string Industry { get; set; }
}
```

The Action in HomeController:

```
public ActionResult CreateCompany()
        {
            // Assume these two lists are working fine.  The form Dropdownlist do list the options form these lists.
            ViewBag.CompanyType = GenericMethods.GetGenericPicks2("CompanyType2").OrderBy(e => e.Name);
            ViewBag.CompanyIndustry = GenericMethods.GetGenericPicks2("CompanyIndustry").OrderBy(e => e.Name);
            return View();
        }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCompany(Company comp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Response.Write("Saving to DB");
            // code to save to database, redirect to other page
            return View(comp);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(comp);
        }


    }
```

Lastly, Here is the Create View.  This view is working fine, showing dropdown lists with options..., but when I click Submit, I received the error described above.

```
@model MVCTest1.Models.Company
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateCompany";
}
<h2>CreateCompany</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Company</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type2, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyType, "Value", "Name"), "Select Option")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Industry, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Industry, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyIndustry, "Value", "Name"), "Select Option")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Industry, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post POST action for your form?

Comment: Because you have not repopulated the `ViewBag` collections you use for the options before you return the view

Comment: @Akash, I have updated with the POST action. I haven't done much with the POST data since I got stuck.  thanks

Comment: @Stephen, would you mind help for sample code?  I am new to MVC stuff.  thanks

Comment: @Milacay : I've posted answer and let me now if there is still any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @StephenMuecke has already suggested the change, you need to populate ViewBag in POST method as well so that it  will be available for your view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCompany(Company comp)
    {
        ViewBag.CompanyType = GenericMethods.GetGenericPicks2("CompanyType2").OrderBy(e => e.Name);
        ViewBag.CompanyIndustry = GenericMethods.GetGenericPicks2("CompanyIndustry").OrderBy(e => e.Name);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Response.Write("Saving to DB");
            // code to save to database, redirect to other page
            return View(comp);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(comp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad. It helped. Hope, you understood the reason for causing that exception.

Comment: Yes, Now I understand the reason why.  If I redirect to another page in POST action, it would be fine without those two viewbags.  Thank you both.